# Misunderstanding the prefix increment

Tags: java, increment, prefix

I don't understand how this method works.
I run the `recur` method and the output starts at 98, gets incremented and I can't seem to understand what's going on later. The output I expected is:

```
a=98
a=99
a=99
a=100
a=100
a=101
```

But the actual output is:

```
a=98
a=99
a=100
a=101
a=100
a=99
```

I found this exercise in a local java testing forum.
So, any explanations would be useful for me.

```
public  class Test  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recur(98);
    }
    public static void recur(int a) {
        if (a <= 100) {
            System.out.println("a=" + a);
            recur(++a);
            System.out.println("a=" + a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 5):

```
recur(98)
    print "a=98"
    recur(99)
        print "a=99"
        recur(100)
            print "a=100"
            recur(101)
                do nothing
            print "a=101" // that's the value of a in recur(100) after being incremented once
        print "a=100" // that's the value of a in recur(99) after being incremented once
    print "a=99" // that's the value of a in recur(98) after being incremented once
```

What you might be missing is that `a` is a local variable, which means each execution of `recur()` has its own copy of that variable, and changing the value in one execution doesn't affect the value of the local variable of other executions.